# Symfony2 : Better pass optimized Array or Entity to view?

Tags: arrays, performance, symfony, view, entity

I was wondering if it is bad for performances to pass a "big" Entity to the Twig view.

Maybe it is better to re-factor this Entity to an optimized Array, with only the proprieties we need in the view ?

Is there any significant difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a huge difference if any at all.  The performance issue would be present during the hydration of the entity before the view (or within Twig Extensions provided the entities are created with them).

A Twig template is compiled to PHP, so the entity would be passed to it by reference, so no slow down there.